# Disable previous date of a date picker according to date selected in a datepicker

Tags: jquery, html

I have two simple jquery date picker that selects arrival and departure date. If user selects a date from arrival datepicker, i want to disable all the previous date in departure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two input text fields with ids `arrival` and `departure` and try this

```
$("#arrival").datepicker({

            showAnim : 'slideDown',
            showOptions : 'slow',
            defaultDate : "+1w",
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            yearRange : "1950:2100",
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#departure").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#departure").datepicker({

            showAnim : 'slideDown',
            showOptions : 'slow',
            defaultDate : "+1w",
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            yearRange : "1950:2100",
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#arrival").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
```

For more [Visit JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Answer (score 0):

**you can do by simple way :**

```
$('#StartDate').change(function() {
            $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" ,$(this).val());
   });
```